# ReactJS router not showing the page name in the URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've used React Router like below:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
  <Route exact path="/home"  component={HomeComponent}/>
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When I use **this.props.history.push("/home")** or **http://localhost:3000/home** page is Moving to Home page, but the url is still http://localhost:3000/.
Routing is working and I am able to navigate to all pages, but in the Top URL bar it is showing http://localhost:3000/ always.

Any Idea why this happens?

Comment: By any chance ae you using multiple Routers in your app. Also are you using MemoryRouter anywhere

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri No, Only one router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether u have implemented any createBrowserHistory, if its there please remove it (assuming it's an implementation issue).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the BrowserRouter to your index.js instead of adding in the inner component.

```
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: Check this example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-ojsuy?file=/app.js:569-581

Comment: I edited my code to the exact code in the turotial, still its the same.. so strange.. :/
Funny part is, the Router is working. I could see a blink of page names.. and it navigates to the page without any issue. The only issue is we cannot see the page URL on top.

Comment: Thats strange indeed. Have you tried with different browsers as well?

Comment: Yes. Even my team member tried in a different system. Still the same. Any chance its a project issue?

Comment: Try to download the sample codesandbox in your local machine and run it to see if its working